# How can I stream all audio from my Mac to my Android phone?

Tags: audio, streaming

I'm sick of switching my headphone jack from my Mac to phone and vice versa. Is there any way to stream all audio playing on my Mac to my Android phone, so I can hear any audio from either my Mac or my phone through the same pair of headphones, at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Airfoil is available cross platform:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rogueamoeba.AirfoilSpeakers

Comment: I can confirm that I got this solution working with minimal effort. It ain't free (I paid $29 after the free trial) but it gets the job done. You install the Android app linked about and then install the transmitter app on your Mac: https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/ Interface was so intuitive and simple I needed no extra instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe not exactly what you want, but I can stream from my phone to my PC using standard Bluetooth A2DP profile.  I can't stream from my Linux PC to my phone :-(.

Just pair the devices and I believe there is graphical tool on MacOSX to choose the source device (on Linux I use pulseaudio pavucontrol).

Comment: Hmm, I googled "a2db mac android" and things like that, but I couldn't find much useful information. Exactly what tool are you talking about?

Comment: As I mentioned -- I am not sure how to do it on Mac, but for Android-Linux I use those tools: https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp

Answer (score 0):

i used the SoundWire
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWire
but it has some kind of delay
i am not sure if it works on mac

Comment: There's no SoundWire for Mac, as they state on their website. There might be a way to get the Linux version working, but I'm not sure.